# How to use JSON data generated by views_datasource as a php array?

Tags: views

I extracted data in JSON Format from a view (using views_datasource). This is the snap-shot of preview of view.

[image]
Now I want to use this data as php array/object so that I can access each field individually and use it. I tried this in my html.tpl.php file (just to see if the data is fetched or not):

```
    $vdata = views_embed_view('view_name');
    $json_data = drupal_json_decode($vdata);
    $thedata = $json_data->nodes->node->title;

    print ($thedata);
```

But this code is not printing anything. Showing error:"`trying to get property of non object`".

I am new to JSON thing so I dont know if that is the correct way to extract the data from it.

I would be very grateful if I could see  a sample of code which does extraction of data and use it as array. Thank you.

Comment: Use print_r($vdata) and print_r($json_data) to see if it's working correctly.  Is the 'datasource' format part of the Default display?  If a different display outputs the datasource, then you need to specify it in your views_embed_view, like views_embed_view('view_name','display_name');

Comment: I tried: print_r($vdata) and its printing something like   {"nodes":[{"node":{"title":"Graduation Day Photo Four","body":"Gra .............................................. and so on. But $json_data and $thedata are not printing anything. and also the drupal_json_decode() is showing the same error. Thank you. Is it okay to use views_embed_view() in this case or I should use something else ?

Comment: Not sure of your specific need, but you can always load a view using $view = views_get_view('sample_view'); If all you're after is the data of a view, you don't need to use the view_datasource module at all.

Comment: Check out: http://drupal.org/node/48816

Comment: @JohnathanElmore . Hey sorry for late response, as I postponed this task for few days. I tried insertview module. But this is not exactly my need. I want to use the data in **JQuery** that I have to write in `template.php`. So I want to get the data in php array format.                                                   I also tried views_get_view() . But this does not return what I want to utilise. The data above in the picture is exactly what I want but in php array format. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnathanElmore I would request you to visit this question where I have asked what exactly I need the data for. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41222/fetching-databody-and-image-from-nodes-to-use-for-jquery-written-in-template-p . Thank you.